# Python: How do I sum integer values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I am trying to write a simple program that takes a dictionary (inventory) of {item: integer}, and then sums the integer values of all the keys.

Currently, this is what I have, and it isn't working:

```
inventory = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 125, 'bow': 1}

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print('Welcome to your pack. Currently you have:\n')
    total_items = 0
    for k,v in inventory.items():
        total_items = total_items + v.get(v, 0)
    return total_items
    print(total_items)
```

This is the error which I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\displayInventory.py", line 16, in 
    displayInventory(inventory)
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\Documents\displayInventory.py", line 7, in displayInventory
    total_items = total_items + v.get(v, 0)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

I am looking for someone to walk me through what I am missing, not simply give the right code to make this happen, as I can't learn this if I don't understand what is going on.

Any insight/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would `sum(inventory.values())` work for you?

Comment: sum(inventory.values()) did work, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop, you are already destructuring each pair "`k, v`" stands for key and value. Hence, you're getting that error because you're trying to get your value, from the value.

Just change the body of your for loop to `total_items += v` and you should get what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that works as well!